# How do I use CreateFromDiscriminatorValue?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have a webhook getting notifications from Teams, and want to deserialize the returned data.

I think the type I'm after is `ChangeNotificationCollectionResponse` but couldn't find this explicitly in the docs anywhere?

Anyhow, if that is the correct type, how are we meant to deserialize it? I see that `ChangeNotificationCollectionResponse` has a method `CreateFromDiscriminatorValue`, and again can't find any docs on that aside from the boilerplate "this thing exists" docs.
Do we use that somehow, and if so can you provide an example or can we just use a regular json deserializer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think one way is to create an instance of `JsonParseNode` and call the `GetObjectValue` method.

```
var jsonContent = "{\"value\":[{\"subscriptionId\":\"xxx\",\"subscriptionExpirationDateTime\":\"xxx\",\"changeType\":\"created\",...]}";
var jsonParseNode = new JsonParseNode(JsonDocument.Parse(jsonContent).RootElement);
var collectionResponse = jsonParseNode.GetObjectValue(ChangeNotificationCollectionResponse.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks mate. Can I ask how you figured this out? Couldn't find any official docs on how to use this stuff.

Comment: Probably from digging thru the unit tests of the MS Graph repo [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/f7f01eeb125d8ed0cb023852b587eb30a0bb39f8/tests/Microsoft.Graph.DotnetCore.Test/Models/ModelSerializationTests.cs#L36). I haven't been able to find much documentation either.